# Error while loading Raster data to a Postgres Table

Tags: postgresql, postgis

I am getting an error while loading Raster data to a postgres table

```
ERROR:  function st_bandmetadata(public.raster, integer[]) does not exist
LINE 1:  SELECT array_agg(pixeltype)::text[] FROM st_bandmetadata($1...
                                                  ^
HINT:  No function matches the given name and argument types. You might need to add explicit type casts.
QUERY:   SELECT array_agg(pixeltype)::text[] FROM st_bandmetadata($1, ARRAY[]::int[]);
CONTEXT:  SQL function "_raster_constraint_pixel_types" during inlining
COPY elevation_hi, line 1: "1   01000001006A98816335DA4E3F6A98816335DA4EBFA2221ECF131C64C0FEE6DF13C4963640000000000000000000000000..."
   3139
```

Any idea on this?

I have below extensions present in the database where I am trying to create the table:

```
CREATE EXTENSION postgis
CREATE EXTENSION postgis_topology
CREATE EXTENSION fuzzystrmatch
```

Please help me on this If you have any idea.

My search path set for the database is ::

```
search_path                      
----------------------------------------------
 "$user", public, rasters, postgis, pg_catalog
```

```
post_GIS version

SELECT postgis_version();
            postgis_version            
---------------------------------------
 2.1 USE_GEOS=1 USE_PROJ=1 USE_STATS=1
```

Please let me knwo if you havve face this issue earlier.

Comment: Hi @Laurenz

I have added all these in my search path but still getting the same error.

alter database my_db set search_path = "$user", public, rasters, postgis, pg_catalog;

Do you have any thought on this

Comment: What do you get for `\dx raster` in `psql`? Can you see the function in `\dx+ raster`?

Comment: Hi @LaurenzAlbe

Below is the result that I got

psql (9.3.24)
Type "help" for help.

postgres=# \dx raster
     List of installed extensions
 Name | Version | Schema | Description 
------+---------+--------+-------------
(0 rows)

postgres=# \dx+ raster
Did not find any extension named "raster".
postgres=#

But in other server also I got the same result where this issue is not appearing.

Comment: You have to connect to the correct database.

Comment: Hi @LaurenzAlbe                                                                                                     I swtiched to the correct databse with it's corresponding user. But still getting the same result.

database=> \dx raster
     List of installed extensions
 Name | Version | Schema | Description 
------+---------+--------+-------------
(0 rows)

database=> \dx+ raster
Did not find any extension named "raster".
database=>

Comment: Then the extensions are not installed, and it is not surprising that you get the error. Try installing them again, you must have made a mistake the first time.

Comment: I have added below extensions : CREATE EXTENSION postgis;
CREATE EXTENSION postgis_topology; ``` But CREATE EXTENSION postgis_raster is telling --> ERROR:  could not open extension control file "/usr/share/postgresql/9.3/extension/postgis_raster.control": No such file or directory; --> postgis version is : POSTGIS="2.1.2 r12389" ... please let me know if you have any idea on this

Comment: You probably have a PostGIS installation older than 3.0.0, where `postgis_raster` was introduced.

Comment: Hi @LaurenzAlbe, There was an issue in the server as a result postgis extension was not getting detected by python script, so admin team has provided a new server which does not have any problem. Currently I am not facing that issue there.Thanks for your support.